# How to plot Vector space model for text clustering?

Tags: c#, winforms, cluster-analysis, k-means, text-classification

I'm using K-Means based text clustering technique. I have a vector space model which is a n-dimensional array of float. I'm running dry of ideas to plot it in the graph. Also my final need after plotting is to have each data points in the plot labelled( mostly with the file name of text document). My work is inspired by https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439890/Text-Documents-Clustering-using-K-Means-Algorithm
If anyone could help in plotting for text clustering , it would be really a great help.

Answer (score 0):

One does not simply <strike>walk into mordor</strike> plot high dimensional data.

Your screen is just 2d, text is high dimensional and sparse.

You can try PCA, tSNE etc., but don't expect them to work as nicely as low dimensional continuous data.